# Установить состояние чекбоксов программно в TreeListControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm, devexpress

Есть в DevExpress компонент TreeListControl под WPF. У него можно установить ряд свойств и чекбоксы будут автоматически переключаться рекурсивно с учетом третьего состояния. Даже можно прибиндиться к свойству модели.

```
ShowCheckboxes="True" AllowRecursiveNodeChecking="True" CheckBoxFieldName="IsChecked"
```

А как, используя MVVM, можно устанавливать состояние чекбоксов, чтобы родительские элементы тоже меняли свое состояние? Например, мне надо инициализировать начальное состояние в модели или в процессе работы программно установить чекбокс: состояние конкретного чекбокса меняется, но родительских - нет. Только по клику работает механизм рекурсивной установки.

Модель:

```
public class FilterModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public List<FilterModel> Child { get; set; }

    private bool? _isChecked = false;
    public bool? IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set { _isChecked = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }        

    public FilterModel()
    {
        Child = new List<FilterModel>();
    }

    ...
}
```

Вью-модель:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<FilterModel> FilterModel { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        FilterModel = new List<FilterModel>();
        var item = new FilterModel() { Name = "First" };
        item.Child.Add(new FilterModel() { ID = 1, Name = "Apple", IsChecked = true });
        item.Child.Add(new FilterModel() { ID = 2, Name = "Sony" });
        FilterModel.Add(item);
        item = new FilterModel() { Name = "Second" };
        item.Child.Add(new FilterModel() { ID = 3, Name = "HTC" });
        item.Child.Add(new FilterModel() { ID = 4, Name = "LG" });
        FilterModel.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: А если сделать `AllowRecursiveNodeChecking="False"`?

Comment: В этом случае (при клике мышкой) не будет происходить смена родительских и дочерних чекбоксов.